# Selenium TypeError: this.tabModal is null

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import *
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.execute_script("alert('qwer');")
print(EC.alert_is_present()(driver))
# driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("alert('qwer');")
```

If we accept the alert manually then an error raised in last line

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: this.tabModal is null
```

After checking the selenium module,
`alert_is_present()` switches to the alert window.
So if try to switch to the main window , but the error is raised again for **every statement** since i running in interactive mode.

```
>>> selenium.__version__ #'3.141.0'
geckodriver -V #geckodriver 0.24.0 ( 2019-01-28)
Firefox -V #67.0 (64-bit)
Windows 10
```

Geckodriver Log

```
Marionette threw an error: TypeError: this.tabModal is null
get ui@chrome://marionette/content/modal.js:159:5
GeckoDriver.prototype._handleUserPrompts@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:3256:23
GeckoDriver.prototype.switchToFrame@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:1672:14
despatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:289:40
execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:262:16
onPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:235:20
onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:236:9
_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:492:20
```

How to solve this without closing the session?

Comment: why not including alert_is_present() in try,except block ?

Comment: @TonyJafar The error is raised in **last line** and after every statement

Comment: I could not reproduce the script works just fine for me

Comment: @TonyJafar Did you manually close the alert box?

Comment: yes i did and I got `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: ur `selenium.__version__`

Comment: 3.141.0 I think it is not the latest though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193990/discussion-between-smartmanoj-and-tonyjafar).